# How to combine DDD on the server with MVP on the client?

Tags: gwt, domain-driven-design, mvp

In our application we've started to use domain-driven-design on the server, whilst at the same time changing our UI technology to GWT, where MVP seems to be the natural choice. Now we're wondering how to combine these two together. In particular: **how should the client-side model be connected with the server-side domain objects?**

One of the advantages of GWT is that you speak in domain terms, which represent what the user really wants to do, so instead of CRUD operations like

```
cook.setFlour(20); 
cook.setOil(10);
cook.setJam(100);
...
```

you only do

```
cook.makeCake();
```

Obviously, unless you're going for a CRUD UI, on the UI we also want to speak in very similar terms (if the UI is supposed to offer something useful, it should also be domain-centric). In such case I imagine that **on the UI we should have also a model with rich domain operations** which would in turn trigger calls to the server, which would internally use the rich domain objects on the server.

So the control flow should look more or less like this:

```
--- user presses a button ---
presenter.handleMakeCakeButton();
this.makeTheUiDisplaySomethingUiSpecific(); // 'this': presenter
model.makeCake();
remoteService.makeCake(this); // 'this': model
--- call to the server ---
service.makeCake(clientSideModel);
cook.makeCake(serverSideModelTranslatedFromAboveClientSideModel); // cook - the domain object on the server side
--- service returns the updated model which is set and displayed on the client side ---
```

**So we get 2 rich domain models. Am I getting something wrong or is the above concept sound? Would you suggest something else? Any good practices/guidelines in this area?**

Comment: Just so we can get a better idea, could you give an example of what the client-side `model.makeCake()` method would do?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips It would call remoteService.makeCake(this) and upon returning, once the data is persisted, it would set client-side state (setFlour, setOil, setJam) so that the view also gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rich domain model isn't just about exposing domain operations on the outside, it's also about enforcing domain invariants and rules and carrying out domain processes on the inside.

Here you don't have 2 rich domain models, you have a rich domain model on the server side and a presentation model on the client side. It turns out that the presentation model has methods named after domain concepts, but that's also the case in about every layer of your system because the Ubiquitous Language is everywhere.

Regarding client side approaches, there's this interesting concept of task-based UIs in the CQRS sphere that you might want to check out : https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/